# Email html to escape gmails promotion tab

Tags: html, email, gmail

Hi i am currently building an html email but when i send it out gmails new file structure puts it in a promotions tab rather than in the primary tab. Does anyone know a way round this?

Comment: What is in the body of your e-mail?

Comment: @icedwater Its essentialy a news letter with a bit of text and a few images that click through to a website

Comment: Let's see what responses this gets. Good luck :)

Comment: Good one - how to defeat Google AI algorithms - I hope there is still a way :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing content not code.

Comment: +1 Perfectly decent question. @Quentin I don't think the OP's customer / boss will see it that way! The correct answer to this question is "there's nothing you can do as a programmer, the GMail user has to change their settings". But that is a useful answer and this **is not** a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want you want to do is (currently) virtually impossible. The "Primary" tab is meant for E-mails targeted for specific person e.g 'the user'. This means that anything sent out as a "broadcast" like your newsletter is  automatically filtered out of the users primary inbox tab.  [This](http://easym6.com/2013/07/31/how-to-use-the-new-gmail-tabs/) page gives a nice overview of the new tabs.

**Workaround**

There is one way to get around this, simply ask your users or those that receive your newsletter to change their settings for the e-mails you send them by dragging one of the 
e-mails you sent them to the primary tab, this should change the settings for all future 
e-mails they receive from you.

check this link out if you have trouble with the above:
http://subscriptionsitecentral.com/get-your-subscriber-emails-into-gmails-primary-inbox/

Answer (score 0):

The new Gmail tabs send any newsletter to the Promotions tab.  This is done automatically and at the time there is no way around this.  What you can do is drag and drop your email from promotions to the Primary tag (which will prompt you to move all further emails from the sender to that location).  This must be done by all your subscribers individually though.  You may consider letting your users know they can do this. You can read more about this and ways to "combat"/relax about the change.

here,

[New-Gmail Tabs](http://menwithpens.ca/new-gmail-tabs/)

and here

[Gmail-Promotions-Tab](http://www.copyblogger.com/gmail-promotions-tab/)

Based on these articles I would say I would't worry too much about the change.