# Code to insert into my emails to avoid spam/promo folders?

Tags: email, html-email, email-spam

Ive heard of people **inputting code into their email systems** to avoid being auto-labelled in Gmail in the promotional tab. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: How to avoid being labelled spam is much too general a question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. But how to avoid being auto-labelled in Gmail in the promotional tab is more specific. Can you edit please to ask that, if that's what you want to know?

Comment: There are already questions and answers on that though - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627421/prevent-sending-mail-to-promotions-in-gmail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808019/email-html-to-escape-gmails-promotion-tab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227773/mailgun-email-reaching-gmails-promotion-tab-not-primary